# AJAX request not returning anything from server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iis, windows-server-2012

I've set up a website on my server using Windows Server2012 R2 version 6.2, using the IIS manager. In my "Default Document" directory on IIS, I have a file named "test.html" and another "ajax_info.txt".

Here's the code for test.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
    // code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the ajax_info.txt file that I reference in test.html:

```html
<h1>AJAX</h1>
<p>AJAX is not a programming language.</p>
<p>AJAX is a technique for accessing web servers from a web page.</p>
<p>AJAX stands for Asyncronous JavaScript And XML.</p>
```

Now, when I run the website and browse it, and press the button for the AJAX request, the info from ajax_info.txt is not returned onto the site. What am I doing wrong, and what can I do make the AJAX request work and receive the info?

---

## Solved

I've since solved this problem, I incorrectly set up a local server on IIS and hence my AJAX functions did not send their requests.

Comment: Have you look to the devtools network tab? Do you see this request and it's response?

Comment: Your AJAX code is from the 19th century. Please investigate the fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @MysterX, where could I find this devtools network tab?

Comment: @Mirza if you are using Chrome or Firefox for testing just press F12 to open devtools and then press on network tab. To catch request reload your page with opened devtools

Comment: @MysterX I've reloaded my page and I could observe a request and its response. However, there is no AJAX request when I press the button.